# Create historical data from Microsoft Excel RTD function

Tags: vba, excel

Need help in saving historical data from =RTD Microsoft Excel function every 5 seconds. I am using Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")) and coping data to another sheet row by row.

Problem is that it's not letting =RTD refresh data during wait interval and the same data keeps getting copied to rows which was there in the cells when the macro was started.

Attaching code and images of cells & historical data.

**My Code:**

```
Sub Macro_CreateHistoricalData()

For i = 1 To 50
Sheets("Sheet1a").Select

Range("Q1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"

Range("Q1:Q4").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select

'Paste special with transpose to other sheet

ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True

Next i

Sheets("Sheet1a").Select
Range("Q1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

[Data to be picked up from first sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4awn.png)

[Output that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOHrz.png)

*******Please ignore the time difference in the two images, it's due to screenshot taken at different times, ideally, the last row should have the time matching with the time in the first image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.Wait` freezes (stops) your application (Excel) for the time you set.

Try it with a timer like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim TimerVal As Integer, TimerCount As Integer

Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long
Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Sub TimerStart(newTimer As Boolean)
  If newTimer Then
    TimerVal = SetTimer(0, 0, 5000, AddressOf TimerTic) '5000 = time in ms >> 5000ms = 5s
    TimerCount = 0
  Else
    KillTimer 0, TimerVal
  End If
End Sub

Sub TimerTic(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long, ByVal TimerCode As Long, ByVal c As Long)      
  If TimerCode = TimerVal And TimerCount < 50 Then 'If Timer is known and tics are left
    Macro_CreateHistoricalData 'Call your macro without Loops
  Else
    KillTimer 0, TimerCode 'Kill the timer so it wont run forever
  End If
End Sub

Sub Macro_CreateHistoricalData()
  TimerCount = TimerCount + 1
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Sheets("Sheet1a").Range("Q1").ClearContents
  Sheets("Sheet1a").Range("Q1").FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
  Sheets("Sheet1a").Range("Q1:Q4").Copy
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(TimerCount, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlNone, False, True
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Start this macro timer with `TimerStart True` or `Call TimerStart(True)`

**Edit:** i played a bit with this macro and found 1 problem :(
when the tic-macro is triggered while you insert text into a cell or something like that, excel may crash :(

so i changed it a lilbit if there is a chance this problem may occour

```
Option Explicit
Dim TimerVal As Variant, TimerCount As Integer

Sub TimerStart()
  TimerCount = 0
  TimerVal = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
  Application.OnTime TimerVal, "Macro_CreateHistoricalData", , True
  'only execute the macro if excel is "ready" to do it
End Sub

Sub Macro_CreateHistoricalData()
  If IsEmpty(TimerVal) Then Exit Sub

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Sheets("Sheet1a").Range("Q1").ClearContents
  Sheets("Sheet1a").Range("Q1").FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
  Sheets("Sheet1a").Range("Q1:Q4").Copy
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(TimerCount, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlNone, False, True
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

  TimerVal = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
  TimerCount = TimerCount + 1
  If TimerCount < 50 Then Application.OnTime TimerVal, "Macro_CreateHistoricalData", , True
End Sub
```

Note: not using `TimerCount = 0` at the very start, will leave the old value. i.e. after 50 counts it stops automatically and `TimerCount` is still at 50. starting the next loop wont work until u reset the macros ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am just a novice with VBA, I usually run macros by clicking Macros button and then clicking Run after highlighting the macro. When I run Macro_CreateHistoricalData, it just runs once and there is no wait.

Comment: if `Application.Wait` isnt your problem im confused... what do you want to know?

Comment: Thanks again. I just tried a few other things. I commented TimerCount = TimerCount + 1 in Macro_CreateHistoricalData() and moved it to  TimerStart replacing TimerCount = 0, appears to be working fine and is letting me change the values manually between iterations. I can't test it with RTD since at this time RTD values are stagnant. They will start changing on monday now, but, I am positive it will work as it let me change values manually between iterations. Thanks so much for giving me the solution. Being a novice, I couldn't have done it even in my dreams without your code. Thanks a bunch...!

Comment: i changed my answer to show an other (better?) way to solve your question... also `Application.OnTime` runs only once and you are not _forced_ to stop it :)

Comment: Surely, it's better and compact too...!!! :) ..I would certainly prefer to use this one..